# Problema con Else en Python 3.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, else

Hace muy poco que he empezado con esto y me ha estado dando un error este código, me gustaría saber si tuve algún error o cómo solucionarlo, gracias.

```
        N1 = input("Dame el valor uno: ")
       N2 = input("Dame el valor dos: ")
       N3 = input("Dame el valor tres: ")

       if N1 > N2:
        if N1 > N2:
            if N2 > N3:
                print (str(N1)+ " - "+ (str(N2)+ " - "+ (str(N3)
            else:
                print (str(N1)+ " - "+ (str(N3)+ " - "+ (str(N2)
        else:
            print (str(N3)+ " - "+ (str(N1)+ " - "+ (str(N2)            
       else:
        if N2 > N3:
            if N1 > N3:
                print (str(N2)+ " - "+ (str(N1)+ " - "+ (str(N3)                
            else:
                print (str(N2)+ " - "+ (str(N3)+ " - "+ (str(N1)
        else:
            print (str(N3)+ " - "+ (str(N2)+ " - "+ (str(N1)
```

Y este es el error que me da:

```
  File "mayor_de_tres.py", line 9
else:
^
       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tienes un problema con la indentación. En python es muy importante ya que define el scope de un condicional, y de no cumplirse correctamente genera un error de sintaxis.

El otro problema es que los paréntesis en los prints no contemplan los cierres correctos.

Intenta probar con el código:

```
    N1 = input("Dame el valor uno: ")
    N2 = input("Dame el valor dos: ")
    N3 = input("Dame el valor tres: ")

    if N1 > N2:
        if N1 > N2:
            if N2 > N3:
                print (str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N3))
            else:
                print (str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N2))
        else:
            print (str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N1)+ " - "+ (str(N2))            
    else:
        if N2 > N3:
            if N1 > N3:
                print (str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N3))                
            else:
                print (str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N1))
        else:
            print (str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N1))
```

Comment: Es cierto que tiene un error de indexación pero, ese supongo que fue a la hora de copiar el código en la pregunta. El error principal es que falta cerrar paréntesis.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias por la observación!

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Literalmente llevo muy poco en esto y cometo varios fallos de este tipo

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a tener paréntesis sin cerrar, de hecho tienes varios paréntesis sin cerrar, especificamente no cierras en la función `str()`. Estos errores son más fáciles de cometer en líneas tan largas como esa. Prueba con esto:

```
if N1 > N2:
    if N1 > N2:
        if N2 > N3:
            print(str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N3) ) 
        else:
            print(str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N2))
    else:
        print(str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N2))            
else:
    if N2 > N3:
        if N1 > N3:
            print(str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N1)+ " - "+ str(N3) )               
        else:
            print(str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N1) )
    else:
        print (str(N3)+ " - "+ str(N2)+ " - "+ str(N1))
```

Comment: gracias funciona perfecto 

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta para que se cierre la pregunta? Gracias. :3